# Can I do a merge conflict post-process step in git?

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on a `git` project where each file has a boilerplate line indicating who last modified it. This line is updated by script each commit, and is invariably a huge cause of merge conflicts that are basically irrelevant, since once the merge is committed the line will get updated again for the merge commit.

I would like to define a custom merge driver (or, failing that, a mergetool) for that would resolve this type of conflict programmatically. This is most easily done from my perspective by either doing a simple text check post-merge and removing the conflict marker from this boilerplate line appropriately.

Unfortunately, it's not that easy, because I can't see anyway to either have git perform a merge using an underlying driver (and whatever settings it may have) or to run my tool with the merged version, rather than having to implement or refer to some other providing 3-way diff. There are also no hooks I can see that would do this.

Can anyone offer suggestions?

Comment: You're using source control.. what is the point of this comment line indicating who last modified the file? Git can tell you that..

Comment: I might be a little of topic, but why do you need something like that on the first place? you can just give `git log -1 --format=%an FILENAME` in your cli, or create a script with that in mind...

Comment: From "Clean Code," by Robert C. Martin, pg.286:

"C1: Inappropriate Information -
It is inappropriate for a comment to hold information better held in a different kind of system such as your source code control system, your issue tracking system, or any other record-keeping system. Change histories, for example, just clutter up source ﬁles with volumes of historical and uninteresting text. In general, meta-data such as authors, last-modiﬁed-date, SPR number, and so on should not appear in comments. Comments should be reserved for technical notes about the code and design."

Comment: It's a licensing restriction. I think it's stupid, but it's not my call. Work with me, please.

Comment: You could try looking into the `rerere` command: http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html - it's meant to redo the same resolution the next time it crops up. I don't think it would replay a resolution from one file to another, but over time, if the same handful of files are being merged back and forth, it might start automatically resolving more and more of these conflicts for you.